# how to restore git user home directory of gitlab

Tags: git, gitlab, gitlab-ce

I accidentally deleted the git user home directory of gitlab-ce (ie /home/git) and couldn't find anyway to restore it. The normally used mkhomedir_helper is apparently not suitable here as gitlab's user home directory has a special structure and doesn't copy files from /etc/skel
So do any one can tell me how to restore the directory? It is really important for the operation of gitlab-ce.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have a backup, try to install it again on a blank machine and copy the folder from there.